# Understanding the practical use of Parents and Inheritance

Tags: java, class, inheritance

If I create a parent class called `Turret` and want to create children of this class `SimpleTurret`, `RapidFireTurret`, `CannonTurret` , how would I call that I want to use `RapidFireTurret` and pull the information for that through the parent `Turret` class?

**EDIT: Added Context**

**Turrets**

```
public class Turrets {

    int health, x, y;

    Bitmap sprite;

    public int getHealth() {return health;}

    public int getX() {return x;}

    public int getY() {return y;}

    public Bitmap getSprite() {return sprite;}
}
```

**SimpleTurret**

```
public class SimpleTurret extends Turrets {

        public SimpleTurret(Context context){

            sprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.simple_turret);

            health = 50;

            x = 100;
            y = 100;
        }
}
```

**GameView**

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    private boolean running = true;

    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getHolder();

    SimpleTurret simpleTurret;

    public GameView (Context context){
        super(context);

        simpleTurret = new SimpleTurret(context);

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running){
            DrawCanvas();
        }
    }

    public void DrawCanvas(){
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawBitmap(simpleTurret.getSprite(), simpleTurret.getX(), simpleTurret.getY(), null);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide code for a better answer but this should answer a bit of your question.

First you need to make the `Turrent` class include all shared fields between the subclasses and then a constructor for setting these fields, along with getters and setters on the `Turrent` class.

```
public class Turrent {

  private int dmg;
  private float fireRate;
  private int maxAmmo;

  public Turrent(int dmg, float fireRate, int maxAmmo){
    this.dmg = dmg;
    this.fireRate = fireRate;
    this.maxAmmo = maxAmmo;
  }

  ///example of a read only field
  public int getDmg(){return this.dmg;}

  public void setFireRate(float fireRate){this.fireRate = fireRate;}

  public float getFireRate(){return this.fireRate;}

  ///other getters and setters plus functional code
}
```

Then you'll want to add the other subclasses. Each subclass should have a constructor that passes in the needed arguments and call the super constructor of the `Turrent` class.

```
public class SimpleTurrent extends Turrent {
  public SimpleTurrent(int dmg, float fireRate, int maxAmmo){
    super(int dmg, float fireRate, int maxAmmo);
  }
/// other code
}
```

You also need to add override methods and any extra methods that need to be in the subclass. These new methods should have different functionality between classes. If they share functionality then they should be included in the `Turrent` class.

```
public class Turrent {

  private int dmg;
  private float fireRate;
  private int maxAmmo;

  public Turrent(int dmg, float fireRate, int maxAmmo){
    this.dmg = dmg;
    this.fireRate = fireRate;
    this.maxAmmo = maxAmmo;
  }

  ///example of a read only field
  public int getDmg(){return this.dmg;}

  public void setFireRate(float fireRate){this.fireRate = fireRate;}

  public float getFireRate(){return this.fireRate;}

  public void attack(Enemy enemy){
    enemy.health = enemy.health-getDmg();
  }

  ///other getters and setters plus functional code
}
_____________________________________________________

public class SimpleTurrent extends Turrent {
  public SimpleTurrent(int dmg, float fireRate, int maxAmmo){
    super(int dmg, float fireRate, int maxAmmo);
  }
  ///overriden method that increases damage based on fire rate
  public void attack(Enemy enemy){
    enemy.health = enemy.health-getDmg()*getFireRate();
  }
  public void simpleTurrentSpecial(){
  ///whatever this could be
  }
/// other code
}
```

If you could explain what you mean by passing data that would be more helpful. For now I assume that you mean that variables are stored on the base class and influenced by the subclass. If your subclasses only have different variable values then there is no need for a separate class (that means functions will never be different between classes.) If that is the case then you should make a builder class that populates variables on the `Turrent` object based on what "type" you want it to be.

```
Turrent newTurrent = TurrentBuilder.makeTurrent("Simple");
```

Look up builder design patterns for more information on that.

Also you need a service class to handle all of this code. It should not be created and used in the `Turrent` class.

```
public class TurrentServiceImp implements TurrentService {

  public static Turrent createTurrnet(String turrentType) {

    return TurrentBuilder.makeTurrent(turrentType);
  }
}
```

I hope this gives you a jump start on what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you update your code and have subclass extend `Turrent`.

Comment: This is a good answer thank you for all the information, I will update my question with that I have started doing  myself and see how different it is! I will be changing my code based on this answer in the next few days, just need to get my head around it all. What I meant by passing data through the parent by the way was, for example, if I want to call a child of Turrets, how do I specify that I want a cretian child and bring the data through to a seperate class. Hopefully this will be more clear in the edit I will add to my question shortly.